# lwjgl XBOX360 (wired) guide button not listing in buttons pressed

Tags: java, input, lwjgl, xbox360

I have a question, how can I get the Guide button (the flashy green cross button on the middle) working. I assume, that maybe it wasn't supposed to use use on other OS-es (e.g.:Linux, mac), but I think, it whould be possible to get it work, hence some of the games could use it. I wish to accomplish this task to get it working with java and LWJGL library.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's specific documentation on the XBOX360 controller with LWJGL, but if there is, I couldn't find it. However, perhaps you can try listing all the individual buttons. I don't have a controller, so I can't test this myself, but maybe:

```
for (int i = 0; i < controller.getButtonCount(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("Button index " + i + " name: " + controller.getButtonName(i));
}
```

where "controller" is your Controller object for your 360 controller.

Comment: I know this, hence I have all the buttons working, except the Guide button. Also the LWJGL don't recognise the xbox360 rublers, sadly :/

Comment: Perhaps you should mention this to the developers. They have contact information on their website.